# Projecting TAB file in QGIS with an unnamed CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, tab

I am working in QGIS and noticed that some of the layers I am using are incorrectly located.

The layers in question are TAB (MapInfo) files which I have dragged in, superimposed on to satellite imagery from XYZ tiles / ESRI imagery and the polyline (in this case, a track) appears around 44m east of where it should be according to the satellite image i.e. it is offset.

I checked for the CRS of the TAB file and it says ''unnamed'' and when therefore I can't reproject the layer.

I am confident in the raster files as importing other data e.g. from a csv, the layers match up.

I normally work in CRS GDA94 (EPSG:28351)

Any solutions? Most of my data has been given to be in TAB format!

Snapshot below:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I meant to edit that to say *60m offset!

Comment: Use the Edit link below your question

Answer (score 1):

You can go to epsg.io website and search the name of the country that your data is located. It will bring all coordinating reference systems used in that area. Then you can choose the projected as you are using meters not degrees.

You can test different CRS from the list in the website by rightclicking on your layer > Layer CRS > Set Layer CRS.

In QGIS you can see in the tiny map if the CRS is covering your shape.

Usually CRS that uses UTM which have a narrow and vertical coverage have such difference with the your usual CRS that you mentioned (GDA94 / MGA Zone family for instance).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by [**@Babak Fi Foo**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401645/49327), if you usually work in CRS GDA94 (EPSG:28351) you can try to change the layer CRS to that *(Note a region can have multiple CRS projection, it is possible that it might not be the right CRS)*.

These articles **Working with Coordinate Reference Systems: Mastering QGIS** from [**GISLOUNGE**](https://www.gislounge.com/working-with-coordinate-reference-systems-mastering-qgis/) https://www.gislounge.com/working-with-coordinate-reference-systems-mastering-qgis/ provides more information on working with CRS. Another good source of information is **Working with Projections (QGIS3)**  from  **QGISTUTORIALS** http://www.qgistutorials.com/fi_FI/docs/3/working_with_projections.html